# A question about a sequence in a Banach Space and series of linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(x_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in a Banach space $E$ such that $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\psi(x_j)| < \infty ~~\forall \psi \in  E'.$$

How can I show that $\sup_{||\psi || \leq 1} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\psi(x_j)| < \infty $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the family $$\mathcal{F} = \left\{\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} c_j\hat{x}_j : j\in \mathbb{N}, (c_j)_{j\in \mathbb{N}}\in \{-1, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\right\}\subset E''$$ where $\hat{x}_j(\psi) := \psi(x_j)$. By the [uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle), as $\sup_{T\in \mathcal{F}} \lvert T(\psi)\rvert = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \lvert \psi(x_j)\rvert < \infty$ for all $\psi\in E'$, we have $$\sup_{\|\psi\|\leq 1} \left\lvert\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} c_j\psi(x_j)\right\rvert = \sup_{\|\psi\|\leq 1} \left\lvert\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} c_j\hat{x}_j(\psi)\right\rvert\leq \sup_{\substack{T\in \mathcal{F}\\ \|\psi\|\leq 1}} \lvert T(\psi)\rvert < \infty$$ for all $(c_j)_{j\in \mathbb{N}}\in \{-1, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, so $$\sup_{\|\psi\|\leq 1} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \lvert \psi(x_j)\rvert = \sup_{\substack{\|\psi\|\leq 1 \\ (c_j)_{j\in \mathbb{N}}\in \{-1, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}}} \left\lvert\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} c_j\psi(x_j)\right\rvert = \sup_{\substack{T\in \mathcal{F}\\ \|\psi\|\leq 1}} \lvert T(\psi)\rvert < \infty$$